# Calculated Field over a Window of Time in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have a table like below:

[image]

```
data trantime_calc;                    
   input TRANTIMESTAMP $ Customer_ID $ Type_Of_Tran $;      
   datalines;         
01AUG2020:21:25:01.49   111 Domestic
02AUG2020:05:38:10.57   111 Domestic
11AUG2020:00:25:35.95   111 International
13MAY2020:16:55:45.15   121 International
20JUN2020:00:58:09.42   121 Domestic
10JUL2020:00:58:09.42   121 Domestic
12AUG2020:18:41:10.80   121 International
14MAY2020:16:02:31.31   341 International
;
```

From the transaction time I want to go back on different windows (12 hours, 1 day, 7 days and 30 days) and calculate if a particular customer has done both "Domestic" and "International" Transactions and then Mark a Yes or No Flag based on the outcome.
The final outcome is like below:

[image]

PS: 1. The code needs to be developed in SAS.
2. The outcome has to be at a customer level.
3. In the original data set, the Trantimestamp is not sorted.

Comment: Your output is not at the customer level.  There are three observations for 111.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join of the table with itself. Use CASE statement to determine if the condition you want to evaluate for a particular new calculated variable is true or not. Use aggregate function, like MAX(), to collapse the conditions to a single result.  MAX() of a boolean will be TRUE if is ever true.  SUM() would instead give a count of the number of times it was true.

First make sure your datetime values are actual datetime values and not character strings.

```
data have;                    
   input TRANTIMESTAMP :datetime. Customer_ID :$10. Type_Of_Tran :$20.;      
   format TRANTIMESTAMP datetime19.;
datalines;         
01AUG2020:21:25:01.49   111 Domestic
02AUG2020:05:38:10.57   111 Domestic
11AUG2020:00:25:35.95   111 International
13MAY2020:16:55:45.15   121 International
20JUN2020:00:58:09.42   121 Domestic
10JUL2020:00:58:09.42   121 Domestic
12AUG2020:18:41:10.80   121 International
14MAY2020:16:02:31.31   341 International
;
```

Then use PROC SQL to do the self join.  It will sort the data for you so it does not need to be sorted first, but performance will be better if the data is sorted and/or indexed properly.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select a.customer_id, a.TRANTIMESTAMP, a.Type_Of_Tran
       , max( case when (b.Type_of_tran='Domestic'
                    and intck('dthour',b.TRANTIMESTAMP,a.TRANTIMESTAMP) <= 12) 
                   then 1
                   else 0 end) as Domestic_12_Hour
       , max( case when (b.Type_of_tran='International' 
                    and intck('dthour',b.TRANTIMESTAMP,a.TRANTIMESTAMP) <= 12) 
                    then 1
                   else 0 end) as International_12_Hour
  from have a
  left join have b
    on a.customer_id=b.customer_id and b.TRANTIMESTAMP < a.TRANTIMESTAMP
  group by 1,2,3
  ;
quit;
```

Results

```
       Customer_                                            Domestic_    International_
Obs       ID              TRANTIMESTAMP    Type_Of_Tran      12_Hour         12_Hour

 1        111        01AUG2020:21:25:01    Domestic             0               0
 2        111        02AUG2020:05:38:11    Domestic             1               0
 3        111        11AUG2020:00:25:36    International        0               0
 4        121        13MAY2020:16:55:45    International        0               0
 5        121        20JUN2020:00:58:09    Domestic             0               0
 6        121        10JUL2020:00:58:09    Domestic             0               0
 7        121        12AUG2020:18:41:11    International        0               0
 8        341        14MAY2020:16:02:31    International        0               0
```

Comment: Thanks you. Just to clarify, the Ask is to Check if a customer has done "Both International and Domestic" transaction in last 12 hours, 1 day, 7 day and so on and create the flag accordingly.

Comment: You can then build the combination from the two separate variables.  `,(calculated Domestic_12_Hour and calculated Intenational_12_Hour) as both_12_hour`